# Finding the core of a 4 player game

Tags: general-topology, game-theory, convex-hulls, utility

How do you find the core of this game?

$V({0}) = V({1}) = \dots = V({4}) = 0 , V({1,2,3}) = V({1,2,4}) = 6, V({1,3,4}) = 5,V({2,3,4}) = 3, V({N}) = 11$

This is supposed to be the core:
$C(v)=conv( { (6,0,5,0), (0,6,5,0), (8,0,3,0), (8,0,0,3), (8,3,0,0), (6,0,0,5), (0,6,0,5), (5,6,0,0), (1,0,5,5) (0,1,5,5) } )$ Where $conv()$ denotes the convex hull of the set of allocations.

I don't see why for example:
$(0,0,5,6)$ is not in there and why $(1,0,5,5) (0,1,5,5)$ are in there

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with the phrase "core of this game".  The added tags reinforce my impression this is related to a convex hull construction, but you've introduced notation without explaining what it means..  What is $N$? What is $v$? Is it different from $V$?

Comment: The imputation $(0,0,5,6)$ is not in the core, since the coalition $\{1,2,3\}$ can block. Since $x(1,2,3)-v(1,2,3) = 5-6=-1<0$, violating the core conditions.

Comment: Ah I think I see. But then the thing that surprises me is that $x_{3}$ does not carry the value 6 anywhere. For instance (0,5,6,0) would also be possible then right? And the last two elements (1,0,5,5),(0,1,5,5) why are those in the core? I really hope I'm not asking a stupid question. Thank you very much for your response!

Comment: For coalition $\{1,2,4\}$ we get the same result as for $\{1,2,3\}$, hence $x(1,2,4)-v(1,2,4)=5-6=-1<0$. The other both imputations are in the core, since no coalition can block. Check it out for all $15$ coalitions, you will observe that the difference is in both cases positive.

Comment: but when we have (0,0,5,6), $ x(1,2,4) - v(1,2,4) = 6 - 6 = 0 $ Is there a good strategy when it comes to finding all the points in the core of a game?

Comment: There are infinite many core allocations, so it is sufficient to determine the extreme points of the core. For convex games we have in total $n!$ core vertices. Have a look in a textbook of convex analysis how to do that.